# How do you say ‘a hell of a’ in a plural form?

Tags: sentence-construction

People say “It’s been a hell of a year”.
But then what about it’s not just one year but the past two or three years (plural)?

Comment: "Heck" (in the title) and "hell" (in the body) basically mean the same thing in this context, but I recommend that you make them consistent, because someone might wonder why you're asking about different phrases.

Answer (score 3):

We say: "It's been a hell of a few years".

Or you can mention the number of years: "It's been a hell of a 3 years" e.g. - @Astralbee

Answer (score 0):

As you would be speaking about those years *collectively*, you would say:

- It's been a hell of a three years.

Alternatively, you could say "*I've had three years of hell*".

Comment: Is it ok if I take part of your answer and credit it? Thanks

Comment: @DialFrost Sure, I already upvoted your answer as it is completely correct, I just thought I'd explain that it is "**a** three years" because they are being spoken of collectively, so that's why the structure doesn't change for being more than one year.